# Error en el tipo de resultado devuelto en una funcion en java

Tags: java, array, funciones, variables, recursión

Recientemente tuve un examen y se me pedía crear un código que dado un array de caracteres me devolviese si este tenía al menos 3 vocales o no. Tenía que hacerlo de forma recursiva, sin bucles. Mi código fue el siguiente:

```
 static boolean esVocal (char c){ //me dice si el char es una vocal
    return c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u';
  }
  
  static boolean hayTresVocales (char[]arr){
    return hayTresVocalesAux (arr,0,0); //recurro a la funcion auxiliar descrita posteriormente
  }
    
    static boolean hayTresVocalesAux (char[]arr, int indice, int contador){
      if (arr.length>=3){ //si el array tiene al menos 3 caracteres
        if (contador==3) //si se encuentran tres vocales devuelve true
        return true;
        if (indice==arr.length) //si el array se recorre entero y no ha encontrado 3 vocales devuelve false
        return false;
        if (esVocal(arr[indice])) //si se encuentra una vocal se suma uno al contador y uno al indice para recorrer el array
        return hayTresVocalesAux (arr, indice+1, contador+1); //devuelvo la misma funcion de forma recursiva
        if (!esVocal(arr[indice])) //si no es una vocal solo se suma uno al indice
        return hayTresVocalesAux (arr, indice+1, contador);
      }
      else //si el array no tiene 3 caracteres devolver falso
      return false;
    }
```

Probando el código al llegar a casa el compilardor me da este error: "Error: This method must return a result of type boolean" en la función auxiliar. ¿Alguien me podría decir donde esta el error? Por lo que yo veo si devuelve un booleano.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: estas devolviendo en varios casos un return fuera de las condicionales para que no te marque error debes usar llaves **if(codicion){return...}**,pero en tu codigo lo mejor es usar una variable tipo boolean que se modifique segun las condiconales ejemplo: boolean variable =true; // if(condicion){varible=false} y al final de tu codigo poner un solo return ...return variable

Comment: Si solo es una línea tengo entendido que se pueden no poner las llaves en el if, el problema creo que estaba en que pongo 4 if con sus distintas condiciones para que devuelva algo y no pongo ningun else por si no se cumpliese nada de lo anterior. Por eso me da error. Muchas gracias aun así.

Comment: @Chona *aparte es buena practica en general tener un solo return en la medida de lo posible* -> Perdona pero me puedes indicar dónde se dice que eso es una buena práctica??? Porque en múltiples sitios aconsejan justo lo que hace el AP aquí, que es primero determinar cuales son tus condiciones de salida, y luego seguir con la lógica. De hecho, hay [preguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement) en SO en inglés en referencia a esto y el consenso general parece ir de acuerdo a lo que digo y hace el AP aquí.

Answer (score 0):

El problema era dentro del primer if en el que hay otros 4 if anidados. El compilador lo revisa y piensa en que si ninguna de las condiciones del if se cumple no puede devolver nada. Por eso da "Error: This method must return a result of type boolean". El código correcto quedaría:

```
static boolean esVocal (char c){ //me dice si el char es una vocal
        return c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u';
      }
  
  static boolean hayTresVocales (char[]arr){
    return hayTresVocalesAux (arr,0,0); //recurro a la funcion auxiliar descrita posteriormente
  }
    
    static boolean hayTresVocalesAux (char[]arr, int indice, int contador){
      if (arr.length>=3){ //si el array tiene al menos 3 caracteres
        if (contador==3) //si se encuentran tres vocales devuelve true
        return true;
        if (indice==arr.length) //si el array se recorre entero y no ha encontrado 3 vocales devuelve false
        return false;
        if (esVocal(arr[indice])) //si se encuentra una vocal se suma uno al contador y uno al indice para recorrer el array
        return hayTresVocalesAux (arr, indice+1, contador+1); //devuelvo la misma funcion de forma recursiva
        if (!esVocal(arr[indice])) //si no es una vocal solo se suma uno al indice
        return hayTresVocalesAux (arr, indice+1, contador);
        }
      return false; //si el array no tiene 3 caracteres devolver falso
      }
```

Comment: En realidad lo que pasa es que sobra el último `else`. Ya que cada condición tiene un `return` es totalmente innecesario poner un `else` al final. Es más fácil dejarlo como `return false;` y solo se ejecutará si el código no ha salido antes por ninguno de los return superiores. Además, tener dos bloques `else return false;` es repetir código innecesariamente... si las condiciones son idénticas, únelas en una misma, no las dupliques

Comment: Okey gracias lo edito, aunque la condición del segundo else es si el array tiene menos de 3 elementos, ya que no podrá haber 3 vocales, y la del primero era que no se cumpliesen ninguno de los if. No sé si eso es repetir código innecesariamente o no.

Comment: Es repetir código por el simple hecho de que dos `else return false;` uno tras otro es lo mismo que no poner ningún else y solo un `return false;`. Lo importante es que si no entra a ningún if, retorne falso... y dado que si entra a algún if se va a salir por el return que toca, si pones un `return false;` al final siempre vas a asegurarte de que o entra a alguno de los if, o es falso. No hay necesidad de else.

Comment: En realidad el segundo `else` es porque si el array no tiene al menos 3 elementos el resultado nunca va a poder ser `true`. Si lo quito va a realizar operaciones innecesarias en arrays de por ejemplo 2 elementos que ya se sabe desde el principio que la respuesta es `false`, y aun así va a recorrer el array para comprobarlo, por eso es que lo pongo... los profesores han dejado claro que el código no debe realizar operaciones innecesarias, pero es cierto que el resultado sería el mismo, gracias.

Comment: Quitar esos `else` no va a implicar ninguna operación más. A no ser que me falle la vista cada uno de tus `if` tiene un return, ergo si no entras a ningún `if`, llegarás al `return false` exactamente igual que si hubieses tenido un `else`. Si cada una de tus condiciones tiene su propio return, cuando ninguna condición se cumple no es necesario un else, es seguro poner un `return false;` al final, porque con que una condición se cumpla, detendrás la ejecución en un return anterior. No veo que quitar el else en este caso vaya a generar ninguna operación innecesaria

Comment: Me refiero a que si no entra a tu primer `if`, saltará directamente al final.... no necesitas tener un `else` puesto que no hay ninguna otra opción. O entra al primer if y sale por alguno de los return de dentro, o va directo al final y sale por el `return false;`. Dado que la función ha terminado en ese punto, no tiene sentido añadir un `else`... o entra por el `if`, o termina. No hay ninguna operación *extra*.

Comment: Ya entendí, cierto, lo edito de nuevo.